# Communication between two sessions of same web application in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem like two clients should be accessing my web application.
My first question is how can i know that two clients exist.

If two clients exist i should have a communication as mentioned below.

Client1 should write
once client1 writes then client2 should read it and will respond
once client2 writes then client1 should read it and will respond
in this pattern my communication should happen.

Any help will be appreciated...Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use **HttpSessionListener** to manage the number of clients in your webapplication during session creation and destruction.Please post more detail about the clients

Comment: Don't use HTTP sessions for this. Instead implement your own component, which will be able to handle this type of communication.

Comment: Pravel Horal...How to do that? do u have any sample?

Answer (score 0):

Create an HttpSessionListener which will maintain a set of active sessions. When a servlet gets a request from client1 save request body in a client1 session attribute then look for client2 session in active session set, if found take body (previous client2 request) from there and send it as a response to client1.

Comment: Not sure whether this is a good approach. IMO session maps and their content is undefined if they are not accessed in the scope of their respective requests.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for `jsr 356.`